# What are the [internal] steps involved in making USB drive 'bootable'?

Tags: boot, usb-drive, dd, bootable, mbr

Whenever I have to install a new Linux distro, I create a bootable USB from the distro image using some specialized program like UNetBootin. Recently, I tried to do for Fedora using **'dd'** command, but after doing so, the BIOS didn't recognize my device. This has lead me to some questions:

1. What are the steps involved in creating a bootable usb? I expect that some kind of MBR should be created at the beginning of the USB device, but **I would like to know the internals of this.**
2. There are a number of examples on the internet about how the 'dd' command can be used to create a bootable USB. So if some kind of MBR *is* required to be inserted, does that mean that the ISO file written using 'dd' command already contanins the MBR? (Because as far as I know, 'dd' just makes a block-by-block copy of a file to a device).
3. What could be the possible reason due to which my USB device became non-recognizable by BIOS?

Comment: does `dd` of a Ubuntu 14.04 image work?  i suspect the Fedora image may be plain ISO and not hard drive bootable.  if your BIOS can emulate a CD/DVD from a USB disk (memory stick is a disk on flash) then use that, else just do Unetbootin.  The details of how to make a disk bootable, which is different than how to make a CD/DVD bootable, are many (not suitable for a comment) ... see Unetbootin source code.

Comment: in short: CDs/DVDs boot method is different than for a disk so images will be formed differently (I've built both and even made a script to convert one to another for early Ubuntu images).